# working with multi-word typedefs

Tags: c++, typedef

I am trying to use typedef's to simplify some repetitive typing, but I need them to be static members.

This works.

```
struct SituationBank
{
    typedef std::vector<std::string> WordType;  
    static WordType location;
};
```

This does not

```
struct SituationBank
    {
        typedef static std::vector<std::string> WordType;   
        WordType location;
    };
```

I've hunted around on the web and experimented, but I cannot seem to find any way of tokenizing a typedef statement with multiple words.  Also, for whatever reason, something like this works just fine. Why?

```
typedef unsigned long long int ulli;
```

Comment: `static` applies to an object (or a function), not a type.

Comment: `typedef` is for creating another name for an existing type; it's not some sort of generic macro replacement as you seem to be imagining

Comment: M.M, What is the problem with using typedef in this manner?

Comment: @mreff555 `typedef` 's only function is to create another name for an existing type. Using it in any other manner is not allowed

Comment: I see.  I wasn't aware typedef's scope limited like that.  I suppose that does explain why static does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`static` is a storage class specifier. It applies to an object or a function, not to a type.

For example, given:

```
static int i;
```

`i` is of type `int`, not of type `static int`. The object `i` is static.

`typedef` creates an alias for an existing type, not for an arbitrary sequence of tokens. (The latter is what macros are for, but they can make your code difficult to read so I wouldn't recommend it in this case.)

Comment: Keith, yes I agree. Regardless, static is specified inline.  If I have to add an extra word to each declaration I will, I was just hoping it could be prevented.